Local variable allocation crashes the stack in embedded C on cortexm4 and operating system
Details: embedded C, cortex M4 with operating system (RTX Kernel), compiled with ARM Compiler V5.06 update6 and Microlib.
Inside a periodic task there are some functons call, one is a debug function:
/**
 * @details
 */
void DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString
(
  const char *  moduleName,
  const char *  string
)
{
  Debug_Message_t * dbgMsg;
  char              tempString[16];
  ...

Context switch, registers are pushed in the stack and the stack pointer gets updated (0x2000FE80 points now to0x2000FE58 as expected, 40 bytes for r0-r8 and LR ).
The local char array tempString is created and the first element is allocated at 0x2000FE58,second one at 0x2000FE59 etc, thus crashing the pushed registers.
Why?
I'd expect the array to grow downards be allocated below the stack pointer, not above. Any hint would be gladly appreciated.
Further clarification becouse I used the wrong wording:
I am not concerned with the fact that array elements are indexed sequentially upwards, this is what I expect. I am concerned with the fact the first element of the array is allocated at the stack pointer after the push instead of allocating 20bytes of ram to the two variables (array and the custom type).
Also, I am not debugging the stack with the debug function. What happens is that the tempString array is populated and destroys the content of the pushed r0-r3.This is why I inspected the code, the assembly and noticed that the tempString is located at the wrong address.
Here is the assembly as per disassembler:
DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString
i.DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString
$Thumb
{
 08006F44   PUSH.W         {R0-R8, LR}
 08006F48   MOV            R4, R0
 08006F4A   MOV            R5, R1
dbgMsg = DebugTask_CreateMessage();

before the push, this code is called:
 08002C28   ADD            R1, PC, #0x016C               ; 0x08002D98
 08002C2A   ADD            R0, PC, #0x0150               ; 0x08002D7C
 08002C2C   BL             DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString  ;0x08006F44

05/08/2024: adding image to clarify what I see pre and post push.
Here the registers and memory dump pre and post push.


Successive array elements are in increasing address in C. This is required by the C standard, per C 2018 6.5.8 5: “… pointers to array elements
with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values…” The only way the hardware addresses can decrease is if the C implementation adds an abstraction layer reversing the addresses or the comparisons of their order, so the addresses in the program differ in behavior from hardware addresses.

If you are tinkering with the stack for debug purposes, you must allow room for local variables, and you should have a thorough understanding of the platform ABI.

The stack grows downward. That means on entering that function, there should be 20 bytes taken from the stack to make room for these 2 variables. Then the start address of the array will be at the bottom of that space (or maybe after the 4 or 8 bytes for the pointer) growing upwards towards the former end of the stack. Putting an array on the stack does not change direction of memory accesses.

Where does the context switch come from that you mention? When does it happen? Before you enter that function? On entering the function? Reserving memory on the stack and storing registers should not affect each other.

@Gerhardh I am familiar on how arrays element are allocated, my concern is about the start of the array that does not reserve those 20 bytes.
Here the assembly ( as seen by Ozone)
DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString
i.DEBUG_Utilities_IndirectTraceString
$Thumb
{
08006F44   PUSH.W         {R0-R8, LR}
08006F48   MOV            R4, R0
08006F4A   MOV            R5, R1
dbgMsg = DebugTask_CreateMessage();

@Catosh Please use the [edit] facility to put all code, error messages etc. in the question itself rather than in comments.

Updated assembly and code in the original post.

Is it theoretically possible that the compiler is aware that r0-r3 are not used later in the code and optimizes the allocation overlapping the stack?

Could you add a bit more assembly code? What code is generated for the function call dbgMsg = DebugTask_CreateMessage();?

Is your code actually "crashing"?  If it is, it is not for the reason you have stated, because that is not happening, and this is an X-Y problem.

I see unexpected behaviours becouse of a sprintf buffer overflow into the buffer and corrupting R4 value. Not a crash, just the lowest byte of the 4 set to zero.

A buffer overflow will not corrupt a register. A buffer overflow will however corrupt the stack with undefined results.  It seems the problem here is the buffer overflow , not the compiler's code generation.  Occam's Razor applies - which is most likely to be wrong - the most basic and fundamental function of a compiler used by thousands of developers for millions of lines of code, or the code you just wrote?  Remember you do not, for the most part, need to know what the compiler does or how - if your code does not work, it is most likely by a very long way that your code is wrong.

I think you have misunderstood what is happening here.  The stack frame already includes the local variables when it is established on entry to the function.  The accesses you are seeing are to the memory allocated to the string, not the pushed registers.  That is, the stack pointer includes the memory for the string, it is not separate
In any event in a context switch the scheduler stores the context of a preempted task and switches to the task stack of the preempting task. The previous context is stored on the stack of the preempted task, not the stack you are observing.
Here your stack frame will comprise of:

16 bytes for the string
4 bytes for dbgMsg
Registers values of the caller saved by the callee (not of the preempted task). Typically may include R4-R8 and R10-R12 (upto 28 bytes).
The return address (4 bytes) or in ARM, the LR value of the caller, LR holds the return address of the callee.

So before any caller register save, that is 24 bytes, then the remaining 16 bytes is the caller saving caller registers that it will modify (4 registers saved).  It does not blindly store all registers, so it is variable.
Note that the precise details may vary somewhat, but the above accounts for your observation without the misapprehension that it somehow involves context storage.

Hi Clifford, I need to look deeper into your answer and then my code. As a minor clarification, there is no a task switch here - the task is already running and a function is called inside the task, so no task pre-emption I'd say. I added a new picture to the original post to clarify what I see. also, please note that dbgMsg is seems to be allocated to a register rather than into ram. Looking at the screenshot, the stack pointer points to 0x2000FE58, that is where the value of R0 is first located. The original stack pointer pointed to 0x2000FE80, just before the push.

@Catosh in your question it was you who referred to the context switch: "Context switch, registers are pushed...".  It is true that it is not relevant, that is exactly what I said, you seem to think otherwise, which is why I addressed it.  I also said "precise details may vary" - that includes register allocation.  Either way, the point is nothing is "crashing the stack", the local array is on the stack, and the stack pointer will be below it.  You seem to be both misunderstanding what is happening and this answer.

I am pretty sure I am misunderstanding more than one thing AND I apologize for being imprecise in my terminology. I had to read your answer twice, then I understood. I can see this push.w{R0, R8. LR} that I understand means to push registers FROM r0 to R8  + LR in ram and then update stack pointer. The stack pointer points to address 0x2000fe58, that is the base address of the first element of the array tempString[16]. The point is that the first 4 register are not pushed to be saved and restored later, but are the ones allocated for the array. Thanks for helping in clarifying.
